# Create complex LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

For the part of database below I need find what team in season scored most goals per one match.

[image: part of database]

For that I used methods

```
public List<Tour> GetAllTours(Guid seasonGuid){...}
```

and

```
public List<SimpleMatch> GetMatches(Guid tour)
{
    using (var db = new ConnectToDb())
    {
        if (!db.Matches.Any()) return new List<Match>();
        var matches = db.Matches;
        var matchesToReturn = new List<Match>();
        foreach (var item in 
            matches
                .Include(x => x.Home)
                .Include(x => x.Guest)
                .Include(x => x.Result)
                .Include(x => x.Tour))
        {
            if (item.Tour.Id != tour)
            matchesToReturn.Add(item);
        }

        return matchesToReturn;
    }
}
```

and

```
public List<SimpleTeam> GetTeamMostGoalInSeason(List<Match> matches){...}
```

where `SimpleTeam` is a team with count goals, if teams with max count == many, used `List`
it's method not tiny, and I don't know how do this with LINQ query.

Comment: If multiple teams scored the same amount of goals per match are you returning all of those teams? Your code says yes but your description says no. Also the relationship between `Matches` and `Results` is wrong. A result could have only 1 match, no? The appropriate relationship is a 1-1 or just removing Results all together

Comment: Yes, relationship `Matches `and `Results` need 1-1, thanks

Comment: @Shoe either is wrong or OP is trying/was asked to have all possible results on a table and just reference in each match the corresponding result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very efficient, but my idea would be something like this:

```
matches.SelectMany(match => new[] {
    new TeamScore {
        TeamId = match.HomeId,
        Goals = match.Result.HomeTeamGoals
    },
    new TeamScore {
        TeamId = match.GuestId,
        Goals = match.Result.GuestTeamGoals
    }
})
.GroupBy(score => score.Goals)
.OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
.First()
.Select(score => score.TeamId);
```

where TeamScore is a simple struct.

This will return an IEnumerable with all the teams that scored the most goals (if it was the same number). You will probably have to change some of the property names or other details. I'm not familiar with LINQ to databases.

If you only want one, you could do First() but that would pick the first one and ignore others depending on the order. SingleOrDefault() would return null when it's a draw, if that's what you want.

EDIT: To get all matches in all tours, you would do something like this:
`GetAllTours(...).SelectMany(tour => GetMatches(tour))`
but since you're dealing with a database, you could just ask for all matches directly.